# How can I make this pig wink and jump? (PROCESSING ANIMATION)

Tags: processing

```java
//pig animation
float x = 100;
float y = 100;
float p = 150;
float l = 10;
float a = 100;
float b = 100; 
float n =20;
int r = 150;
int t = 100;
int s = 100;
int w = 60;
int h = 60;
int z = 11; 
int eyeSize = 10;
int pigNose = 30;
int pigBody = 30;
int pigEars = 35;
int pigTail = 20;
int otherpigTail = 200;
int speed = 1;

void setup () {
  size (600, 600);
  a = width/2.5;
  b = height/2;
}

void draw() {
  background(184, 233, 249);

  //Draw legs
  stroke(0);
  fill(249, 137, 244);
  rect(x+(2*w), y+h/3.5, z, 2*z);
  rect(x+(w), y+h/3, z, 2*z);
  rect(x+(1.5*w), y+h/3, z, 2*z);
  rect(x+(2.5*w), y+h/3.5, z, 2*z);

  ////draw body
  stroke(0);
  fill(249, 137, 244);
  ellipse(110+x,y-pigBody, p, p-20);

  //draw tail
  fill(0);
  line(185+x, y-pigTail, x+otherpigTail, y-(2*pigTail));

  // Draw payer's head
  fill(249, 137, 244);
  ellipse(x,y-pigNose,t,t);

  // Draw player's eyes
  fill(0);
  ellipse(x-w/3+1,y-h/2,eyeSize,eyeSize);
  ellipse(x+w/3-1,y-h/2,eyeSize,eyeSize);

  //Draw nose
  stroke(0);
  fill(198, 105, 194);
  ellipse(x, y, pigNose, pigNose);

  //draw ears
  stroke(0);
  fill(198, 105, 194);
  ellipse(x-(w/2),y-h, pigEars, pigEars);
  ellipse(x+(w/2),y-h, pigEars, pigEars); 
}

class Pet {
  float pigX;
  float pigY;
}
```

I have to make animations appear for this pig under the Class Pet section. I'm not exactly sure how to do this, so if you guys could help that would be great!

Even just an example with an ellipse or something would help.  Also, have I set this up correctly so far?

Answer (score 0):

Please note that you aren't actually using your `Pet` class. You never create an instance of it. You're still just using the variables at the top of your sketch. Please see my answer to [your previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40877281/need-help-adding-a-class-and-animations-to-a-simple-pet-drawing) for an explanation of how to use a class instead of variables at the top of your sketch.

As for a winking eye, you need to take a step back and ask yourself exactly what that looks like. If you have a circle for an eye, what would winking look like? Try to describe what it's doing, in English. Write down a series of steps that you could give to another person who has no idea what you're working on, and have that person describe exactly what's happening to you. Have them draw out each frame, and see what they draw out. Hint: The `ellipse()` function takes arguments for both its `width` and `height`. You could use them.

More generally, I really suggest getting into the habit of trying something out before you post a question on Stack Overflow. Stack Overflow isn't really designed for general "how do I do this" type questions. It's designed for more specific "I tried X, expected Y, but got Z instead" type questions. You need to get into the habit of at least coming up with the steps in English (also known as an algorithm) that you want to accomplish, and then we can go from there. Break your problem down into smaller steps: instead of posting about your entire pig, just post the eye part. Try to get that look like it's blinking, and then add that back to your main sketch. Also note that you have asked several questions here, but you've never accepted any answers, which a lot of people don't like.

Anyway I'd love to continue helping you, but you have to get into the habit of breaking your problem down into smaller steps, writing out exactly what you want to do in English, and then trying something before posting. Good luck.